# Step by Step tutorial how to create a mode in CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror, mode

Can anybody provide me a step by step tutorial in order to create a own mode for CodeMirror.
The online tutorial is quite complicated.

Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [this site](https://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html), it has a great tutorial for "simple modes", if its your case. Also I'll show you a mode that I made for a pseudo-regex mode:

```
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("simplemode", {
    start: [
      // As you can see I use different tokens for different matches as needed.
      {regex: /(\.\+|\.\*|\.|\+)/, token: "keyword"},
      {regex: /(\\d)|(\\w)|(\\s)|(\\t)|(\\r)|(\\n)|(\\\()|(\\\))|(\\\[)|(\\\])|(\\\{)|(\\\})|(\\\.)|(\\\-)|(\\\_)/i, token: "string"},
      {regex: /(![A-Za-z]+\{|\})/, token: "number"},
      {regex: /(\(|\)|\||\[|\]|\-)/, token: "operator"}
    ]
 });
```

Then just add `mode: "simplemode"` to the editor options. Hope it helps you!